# Height appears different between calculation and assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm currently working on a full screen website. It has a main Content section, a header and a navigation bar.
My goal is to have a fixed-height header and navigation, as well as a dynamically-fitting content. I've been working on the project for a couple of days know and my resizing algorithm worked fine until now:

```
var resizeBg = function() 
{
    var newHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

    console.log($(window).innerHeight());

    console.log(newHeight);

    newHeight -= $("#navBar").height();

    console.log(newHeight);

    newHeight -= $("#mainHeader").height();

    console.log(newHeight);

    $("#mainContent").css("height", newHeight + "px");
};

$(window).load(resizeBg);

$(window).resize(resizeBg);
```

The log says:

```
21
21
-45
-128
```

Now, the main content just disappears when using Mozilla Firefox 23.0.1. In other browsers everything works ok. 
Via debugging i found out that `newHeight` would turn negative. After some more debugging I was very confused by following result.
[image: A screenshot of Firebug's debugging surface]

As shown in the picture, the variable `newHeight` has been set to `21` even though the value of `innerHeight` is `629`! Also, the Value `21` seems not to change when varying the window size (although `629` does).

I have no idea what I have done to achieve this error or how to approach this problem.

Comment: Appears to work fine in a simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/cg8Qa/. What happens when you log the values?

Comment: Did you add any watch expressions which would assign a value to newHeight?

Comment: Added log data to the question. NewHeight is encapsuled in ´resizeBg´, i do not have any other methods messing with it.

Comment: Your console output disagrees with your screenshot. Where did the 629 come from?

Comment: @JasonP That's exactly my problem! 629 Is comming up when hovering over 'innerHeight', and 21 is comming up when hovering over 'newHeight' in the debugger (paused right after the assignment)!

Comment: Hm, unless firebug has changed, just hovering a function shouldn't execute the function. Maybe you're seeing something you aren't expecting. Try just using `window.innerHeight` instead of the jquery function.

Comment: Using `window.innerHeight` instead of `$(window).innerHeight` seems to work! But I'm still curious about why JQuery wouldn't work and what's up with that bug.

Comment: Glad it works.. unfortunately, I have no idea on the "why".

Comment: The [jQuery page on `innerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/#innerHeight) says, "This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use `.height()` instead."

Comment: @MrLister Ah, thanks. When in doubt, RTFM I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The jQuery page on innerHeight says, "This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .height() instead." –  Mr Lister Aug 28 '13 at 6:54

Mr Lister is right. I changed the code to:

```
var resizeBg = function() 
{
    var newHeight = window.innerHeight - $("#navBar").height() - $("#mainHeader").height());

    $("#mainContent").css("height", newHeight + "px");
}
```